# Why is my ipod shouting everything at me?

Tags: ipod

I must have triggered some bizarre mode and I don't know what it is or how to turn it off.

I can't get it to happen predictably-- whenever I *try* to make it talk, it won't. But whenever I try to just put on a song and listen, it starts saying the name of the song and artist, then reading off the names of random playlists even though I'm not using a playlist; I always just pick out of Artists. And it does it *repeatedly, it won't %^@#ing stop.* It's **infuriating.** I'm trying to listen to a song and it just keeps telling me the name of the song.

Is it broken??

It's the newest nano.

Comment: It's call VoiceOver, I think. Triple press the home button and it should stop.

Comment: Close. It was speakhints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just google Speakhints and figure out how to turn it the hell off.